# xpath to concatenate soap payload values

Tags: xpath

I have below code which comes as soap body for an API call. I need to get this values as '#06164F4','00000116','##00000130' and values continues.. with single quote and comma separated. I tried with concat and string-join, but could not get exact output. How do get all TOLL_NUMBER from the soap body payload.

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:v1="http://www.oracle.com/Argus/Contract/v1.0" xmlns:v11="http://www.oracle.com/Argus/Types/v1.0">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <ns0:SFT_MSG ns1:Type="Request" ns1:EnterpriseShortName="ns0:EnterpriseShortName_1" xmlns:ns1="http://www.oracle.com/Argus/Base/v1.0" xmlns:ns0="http://www.oracle.com/Argus/TOLL_Request/v1.0">
  <ns0:TOLL_LOOKUP>
    <ns0:TOLL>
      <ns2:TOLL_NUMBER xmlns:ns2="http://www.oracle.com/Argus/Entity/v1.0">#06164F4</ns2:TOLL_NUMBER>
      <ns2:EXPIRATION_DATE xmlns:ns2="http://www.oracle.com/Argus/Entity/v1.0">ns1:EXPIRATION_DATE_0</ns2:EXPIRATION_DATE>
    </ns0:TOLL>
    <ns0:TOLL>
      <ns2:TOLL_NUMBER xmlns:ns2="http://www.oracle.com/Argus/Entity/v1.0">00000116</ns2:TOLL_NUMBER>
      <ns2:EXPIRATION_DATE xmlns:ns2="http://www.oracle.com/Argus/Entity/v1.0">ns1:EXPIRATION_DATE_0</ns2:EXPIRATION_DATE>
    </ns0:TOLL>
    <ns0:TOLL>
      <ns2:TOLL_NUMBER xmlns:ns2="http://www.oracle.com/Argus/Entity/v1.0">##00000130</ns2:TOLL_NUMBER>
      <ns2:EXPIRATION_DATE xmlns:ns2="http://www.oracle.com/Argus/Entity/v1.0">ns1:EXPIRATION_DATE_0</ns2:EXPIRATION_DATE>
    </ns0:TOLL>
  </ns0:TOLL_LOOKUP>
  <ns1:EXTENSION>
    <ns1:CUSTOM ns1:Name="ns0:Name_0" ns1:Metadata="ns0:Metadata_1">ns0:CUSTOM_0</ns1:CUSTOM>
    <ns1:SFT_MSG_ELEMENT>
      <any0>anyContents0</any0>
    </ns1:SFT_MSG_ELEMENT>
  </ns1:EXTENSION>
</ns0:SFT_MSG>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

With XPath 2.0, you can use a combination of `concat()` and `string-join()`...

```
concat("&apos;",string-join(//*:TOLL_NUMBER,"&apos;,&apos;"),"&apos;")
```

Note: It would be preferable to bind the namespace uri `http://www.oracle.com/Argus/Entity/v1.0` to a prefix and use that instead of `*:TOLL_NUMBER`.